# I can't view table date in Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a an app deployed on Heroku based on this tutorial. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I can't view all the data inside one of my tables. Is this a Postgres feature? I'm new to Postgres and DBs.

List of tables

```
my-heroku-app::DATABASE=> \dt
                 List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |     Owner      
--------+-----------------+-------+----------------
 public | alembic_version | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
 public | followers       | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
 public | message         | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
 public | notification    | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
 public | post            | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
 public | user            | table | ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But I get a strange output. However, this should be a table of users who've registered with my blog. I have created several users already and the other table foreign keys can successfully reference them.

```
SELECT * FROM user;

output:
      user      
----------------
 ufzxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I `SELECT` from any other table I get the whole table as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM post;

output:
 id |       body        |         timestamp          | user_id | language 
----+-------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------
  1 | dfdf              | 2020-08-01 03:30:14.529142 |       1 | de
  2 | Hello World       | 2020-08-01 03:30:20.730316 |       1 | de
  3 | you               | 2020-08-05 22:50:34.305096 |       2 | de
  4 | aaa               | 2020-08-21 13:36:38.617855 |       4 | de
  5 | new post from aaa | 2020-08-21 13:49:09.278394 |       4 | de
  6 | adefbg            | 2020-08-23 04:13:46.77888  |       5 | de
  7 | sdvc              | 2020-08-23 04:13:49.32016  |       5 | de
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have named your table `user` because it conflicts with the `user` keyword.

You can get around this problem by using one of these forms to disambiguate:

```
select * from public.user;

select * from "user";
```